# How to select element under currently hovered element

Tags: jquery

I have a `div` containing content that I want to show a `title` pop-up when hovered on. I also want the entire `div` area to be clickable. To make the entire `div` clickable I have created a single anchor that is `position:absolute`d to the top left of the `div` and is made the full width and height of the `div`. This way even the white space of the padding is clickable. However, the element that needs to be hovered on is no longer hover-able.

Is there a way to determine what is under the mouse on hover (other than the current element) so that the `title` attribute can be activated? I have no idea where to begin with this. My initial thinking is storing the positions of the elements I want to hover over in an array and when I hover over the anchor element check the mouse position and if it falls within the desired co-ordinates, then trigger the hover. What javascript do I need to use?

Here is a simple example with only one item that I want to hover over, however in reality I have a deeply nested number of `div`s, `ul`s, and multiple `img`s and it's the `img`s I am wanting to hover over.

```css
.outter {
  position:relative;
  padding:1em;
}
a {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  text-indent:-9999em;
}
```

```html
<div class="outter">
  <div class="inner">
    <p>None of the below will show hovered text on hover</p>
    <span title="Hovered over one">Element One</span><br/>
    <span title="Hovered over two">Element Two</span><br/>
    <span title="Hovered over three">Element Three</span><br/>
  </div>
  <a href="#">Hover on the span for more information</a>
</div>

<div class="outter">
  <div class="inner">
    <p>All the below will show hovered text on hover</p>
    <span title="Hovered over one">Element One</span><br/>
    <span title="Hovered over two">Element Two</span><br/>
    <span title="Hovered over three">Element Three</span><br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have no idea of where to begin with this.

Comment: there are plenty of libraries and tutorials out there to show you how to do tooltips

Comment: That's not the issue. How do I trigger hover on an element under an absolutely positioned anchor?

Comment: The div is able to handle a click event. You don't say what you want the click to do, but you are better off just [changing the cursor on the div to indicate to the user it is clickable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) than covering the whole thing in an anchor tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @IvanChepurin answer (before update) I have made the `div` clickable, changing the url to the anchor in the `p` tag (nice fallback location).

```js
  $('.outter').on('click', function(){
    location = $(this).find('p a').attr('href');
  });
```

```css
.outter {
  position:relative;
  padding:1em;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outter">
  <div class="inner">
    <p> <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/q/29703037">None of the below will show hovered text on hover</a></p>
    <span title="Hovered over one">Element One</span><br/>
    <span title="Hovered over two">Element Two</span><br/>
    <span title="Hovered over three">Element Three</span><br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use your div with a click() event, it seems like a much cleaner soulution than a 100% width and height anchor? That would also deal with your hover problem.

Could also use an anchor with a display:block parameter INSTEAD of a div.

### UPDATE

```
$('.hoverDiv').hover(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.inner').css({
        display: 'block'
    });
}, function() {
    $(this).siblings('.inner').css({
        display: 'none'
    });
});

// clickable
$('.hoverDiv').click(function(){
    $('.outter').append('<p>click!</p>');
});
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z86hj2k6/)

Not sure if this is the structure you have, but it should give you the idea how to solve a problem for your structure.